# Rowwise find most frequent term in dataframe column and count occurrences

Tags: r, tidyverse

I try to find the most frequent category within every row of a dataframe. A category can consist of multiple words split by a /.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)

# example data
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
categories <- c("apple,shoes/socks,trousers/jeans,chocolate",
                "apple,NA,apple,chocolate", 
                "shoes/socks,NA,NA,NA",
                "apple,apple,chocolate,chocolate")

df <- data.frame(id, categories)

# the solution I would like to achieve
solution <- df %>% 
  mutate(winner = c("apple", "apple", "shoes/socks", "apple"),
         winner_count = c(1, 2, 1, 2))
```

Based on these answers I have tried the following:
[Write a function that finds the most common word in a string of text using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711312/write-a-function-that-finds-the-most-common-word-in-a-string-of-text-using-r)

```
trial <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(winner = names(which.max(table(categories %>% str_split(",")))),
         winner_count = which.max(table(categories %>% str_split(",")))[[1]])
```

Also tried to follow this approach, however it also does not give me the required results
[How to find the most repeated word in a vector with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632957/how-to-find-the-most-repeated-word-in-a-vector-with-r)

```
trial2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(winner = DescTools::Mode(str_split(categories, ","), na.rm = T))
```

I am mainly struggling because my most frequent category is not just one word but something like "shoes/socks" and the fact that I also have NAs. I don't want the NAs to be the "winner".
I don't care too much about the ties right now. I already have a follow up process in place where I handle the cases that have winner_count = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split the `categories` on comma in separate rows, `count` their occurrence for each `id`, drop the `NA` values and select the top occurring row for each `id`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(categories, sep = ',') %>%
  count(id, categories, name = 'winner_count') %>%
  filter(categories != 'NA') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max(winner_count, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  rename(winner = categories) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'id') -> result

result

#    id winner      winner_count categories                                
#  <dbl> <chr>              <int> <chr>                                     
#1     1 apple                  1 apple,shoes/socks,trousers/jeans,chocolate
#2     2 apple                  2 apple,NA,apple,chocolate                  
#3     3 shoes/socks            1 shoes/socks,NA,NA,NA                      
#4     4 apple                  2 apple,apple,chocolate,chocolate
```